# How to set active icon colour in Sencha Touch 2.2 Tabpanel app

Tags: sass, icons, themes, sencha-touch-2

I've been having difficulty changing the active colour of an icon in my tabpanel item in Sencha Touch 2.2. I've tried lots of variations of CSS and SASS but have not managed to change it. The CSS I have tried:

```
.x-tabbar.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active {
color: #000000;
background-color: #000000;

}

.x-tab-active {
background-color: #000000;
color: #000000;
}
```

I've also tried setting the active colour in SASS, but this doesn't seem to work either. The only bit of CSS that seems to have that blue in it is this bit:

```
.x-tabbar-light .x-tab-active .x-button-icon::before {
color: #1da2ff;
}
```

...but when I try setting that to black, nothing happens! Anyone have any ideas how I can change it??

[image: Screengrab of Touch 2.2 Project]

EDIT: I tried the first suggestion changing the CSS to this:

```
 .x-tabbar-light .x-tab-active .x-button-icon {
 background-color: #000000;
 }
```

...but this is what I see:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `color: #1da2ff;` to the `:before` pseudo-element is the right thing.

The reason why it doesn't work for you is that the rule get overridden by another one with a more specific selector:

```
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active .x-button-icon:before {
  color: #50b7ff;
}
```

This is the exact situation where using `!important` is appropriate and not shameful:

```
.x-button-icon:before {
  color: #1da2ff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea by selecting the icon, which is a span, and not the wrap, which is a div.

The div wrap .x-tab-active has a background color that decides the background of the active box.  The icon has an image mask so background color or background-image gradient will determine the color of the icon.  There is an additional span that wraps the text, like "x-button-label, for which a color style will change its color.

For changing the color of the icon try:

```
.x-tabbar-light .x-tab-active .x-button-icon {
   background-color: #1da2ff;
 }
```

Comment: Hi,thanks I just tried it and it sets the background of the icon font but not the actual font. I have updated the question with a new pic to show what happens. I think something must have changed in Sencha Touch v2.2 with the new icon font but I can't work out what!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it was enough to add this in my CSS:

```
.x-tabbar-light.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active .x-button-icon:before {
color : #000;
```

}

There was no need to add !important for me as I was using the new base theme for ST 2.2, but your solution worked great!

:-)